# Bluetooth connection using Winsock c++

Tags: c++, sockets, bluetooth, winsock, winsock2

I'm currently working on a project trying to connect two PC's using Bluetooth and Winsock, my idea is to develop a server/client connection between them and send a string from the client to the server but unfortunately, it is not working as I was expecting.

When I run the server code it keeps waiting for the client request and only shows in the console "Listen() is ok! Listening for connection". And when I run the client code it runs the entire code until it shows the message "WSACleanUp() works fine". I paired both computers because I thought it was necessary to do so.

My initial guess is that the client connection to the server is not working. I'm new using Winsock and I'm struggling to find accurate information that could help me to fix these issues (besides some questions previously posted and documentation from windows).

Server code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<ws2bth.h>
#include<bluetoothapis.h>
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<string>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
DEFINE_GUID(GUID_NULL, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //INTIALIZE WINSOCK

    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't initialize winsok" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //CREATE A BLUETOOTH SOCKET

    SOCKET server = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "> Server Socket created" << endl;
    }

    //AUTO ALLOCATION FOR SERVER CHANNEL 

    SOCKADDR_BTH hint;
    memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
    hint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    hint.port = 0;
    hint.btAddr = 0;
    hint.serviceClassId = GUID_NULL;

    //BINDING

    if (bind(server, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Bind() failed with error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(server);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Bind() is ok" << endl;
        cout << "Waiting for client" << endl;
    }

    //LISTENNING 
    
    if (listen(server, SOMAXCONN) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Listen() is ok! Listening for connection" << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Listen() failed with error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(server);
        return;
    }

//WAIT FOR CONNECTION

    SOCKADDR_BTH client;
    int clientSize;
    SOCKET clientSocket;

   for (;;)
    {
        clientSize = sizeof(client);
        clientSocket = accept(server, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            cout << "Accept() failed with error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Connection accepted" << endl;
            printf("Connection came from %04%08x to channel %d\n", GET_NAP(client.btAddr), GET_SAP(client.btAddr), client.port);
        }

    }
const char *sendbbuf = "Test data from receiver...";
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";

    int bytesrec;

    do 
    {
        //ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

        //WAIT FOR CLIENT TO SEND DATA

        bytesrec = recv(clientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (bytesrec > 0)
        {
            cout << " " << bytesrec << " Bytes received" << endl;
        }
        else if (bytesrec == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client disconnected" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "recv() failed with error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
} while (bytesrec > 0);
//ECHO MESSAGE BACK TO CLIENT

    bytesrec = send(clientSocket, recvbuf, bytesrec, 0);
    if (bytesrec == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Sened() failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Send() is ok" << endl;
        cout << "Bytes sent: " << bytesrec << endl;
    }
    if (closesocket(server) == 0)
    {
        cout << "CloseSocket is ok" << endl;
    }
    if (WSACleanup == 0)
    {
        cout << "WSACleanUp ok" << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

CLIENT CODDE

```
#include<iostream>
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<ws2bth.h>
#include<bluetoothapis.h>
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<string.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512


using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //SERVER BLUETOOTH ADRESS

    //BTH_ADDR addr = 0xB0FC3616D3EE;
    
    //INTIALIZE WINSOCK

    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't initialize winsok" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //CREATE A BLUETOOTH SOCKET

    SOCKET client = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

    if (client == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket" << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Socket created" << endl;

    }

    //AUTO ALLOCATION FOR SERVER CHANNEL 

    SOCKADDR_BTH hint;
    memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
    hint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    hint.port = 0;
    hint.btAddr = BTH_ADDR(0xB0FC3616D3EE);
    hint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID;


    int connResult = connect(client, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "Can't connect to server, ERR #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(client);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connected" << endl;
    }

    const char *sendbuf = "Test data from client..";
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";

    int res = send(client,sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), MSG_OOB);

    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Send() failed with error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(client);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Send() is ok" << endl;
        cout << "Bytes sent: " << res << endl;
    }
    res = shutdown(client, SD_SEND);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Shutdown() failed with error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(client);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Shutdown() is working" << endl;
    }

    //RECEIVE DATA

    do
    {
        res = recv(client, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (res > 0)
        {
            cout << " " << res << " Bytes received from sender" << endl;
        }
        else if (res == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client disconnected" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "recv() failed with code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }

    } while (res > 0);

    if (closesocket(client) == 0)
    {
        cout << "CloseSocket() works fine" << endl;
    }
    if (WSACleanup() == 0)
    {
        cout << "WSACleanUp() works fine" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: 1. You must set correct sevrice UUID. 2. Your socket is synchronous. You must use WSAEventSelect to make it async. 3. You missed setsockopt().

Comment: How do I properly set the UUID? the  setsockopt() function goes before or after the binding?

Comment: hint.serviceClassId = <your_uuid>;  setsockopt() - does not matter when.

Comment: About the UUID, do I need to specify the UUID in the client code? or it needs to go in both server and client?

Comment: You have to provide service's UUID on both sides. Also you need to setup the RFCOMM channel number. It can be BTPORT_ANY.

Comment: I'm currently trying to only connect both computers without sending data but I can't make it work. I already tried to change the UUID but I have the same problem, the server keeps waiting for the connection, and the client shows that it is already connected. Here is the link to the code that I'm using, I hope you can check it and help me to fix this issue : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YCvBurw_BcomTrpEEpeC6TXnpwywZej-?usp=sharing

Comment: UUIID must be valid GUID, not NULL one. You can use SPP UUID. Invalid port on server and client sides (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2bth/ns-ws2bth-sockaddr_bth)

Comment: I'm trying to use the SSP UUID: GUID nguiD = { 00001101 - 0000 - 1000 - 8000 - 00805F9B34FB }; But it gives me the error "invalid octal digit"

Comment: bthdef.h SerialPortServiceClass_UUID

Comment: So, I need to use hinit.serviceClassId = SerialPortServiceClass_UUID?

Comment: Yes, something like that